# Session object using ServletContext

Tags: java, servlets

Is there any way to get an object which will be there throughout the session  from ServletContext object??

Comment: Why can't you use the request object?

Comment: What do you want to do with the session in the servlet context?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get the session from the ServletContext.The point of the ServletContext is to get application scope attributes rather than session scope.